# Use Arial font in KOMA Class for section Headings

Tags: fonts, sectioning, koma-script

I would like to use Arial in this document (see below). For some reason the KOMA Class seems to change the section heading font to some other font than Arial. If I change the class to e.g. report it works fine. What is the problem here?

```
\documentclass[12pt, numbers=noenddot,parskip,headings=small,headsepline,listof=nochaptergap, listof=totoc,index=totoc]{scrreprt}

    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{Arial}

    \begin{document}
    Test Text
    \chapter{Heading}
    Test Test Test
    \section{Header}
    Test Test
    \subsection{Heading}
    Test

    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

KOMA-Script classes use by the default the font family choosen with `\setsansfont` for the headings and similar elements.

So you can use either

```
\setsansfont{Arial}
```

or

```
\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalfont\normalcolor\bfseries}
```

Another possibility is setting the class option `sfdefaults=false`.

But Arial is a sans serif font. So maybe its better to use

```
\documentclass[12pt, numbers=noenddot,parskip,headings=small,headsepline,listof=nochaptergap, listof=totoc,index=totoc]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
Test Text
\chapter{Heading}
Test Test Test
\section{Header}
Test Test
\subsection{Heading}
Test
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much. I have a follow up question for this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/382933/use-arial-font-in-koma-class-for-section-headings-and-have-siunitx-in-math-font

Comment: For koma  v3.39 or newer there is now the class option `sfdefaults=false` instead of `egregdoesnotlikesansseriftitles`

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thank for the hint.