# Use Arial font in KOMA Class for section Headings and have siunitx in math font

Tags: math-mode, fonts, koma-script, siunitx

Follow up question for [Use Arial font in KOMA Class for section Headings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/382918/use-arial-font-in-koma-class-for-section-headings)

- I need to the typical italic, math-font for equations using siunitx and normal Arial for headings and text.
- I would like to have normal Arial font where I use siunitx \SI{}{} in an table environment.
- Basically I want everything in Arial, only equations and SI units in them should have the italic math font.

Is this possible?

Here is my MWE which shows all possible situations in my text.

```
\documentclass[12pt, numbers=noenddot,parskip,headings=small,headsepline,listof=nochaptergap, listof=totoc,index=totoc]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[a4paper, includehead, left=3.5cm, right=1.7cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,amsmath}

\usepackage[group-separator={.}]{siunitx}
\sisetup{load-configurations = abbreviations}
\sisetup{locale = DE}
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}
\sisetup{detect-all, math-rm = \ensuremath}
\sisetup{detect-all}                                        


    \begin{document}

    \chapter{Heading}

    Test Test

    \begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
    t_a  = & \frac{v}{a} \\
    h_a  = & \frac{1}{2} \times a \times {t_a}^2 \\
    h_v  = & h_t - h_a - h_r \\
    t_v  = & \frac{h_v}{v} \\
    t_t  = & 2 \times (t_a + t_v + t_r + t_d)
    \end{aligned}
    \end{equation}  
    Equation 1.1 works fine. No SI in there.
    \begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
    h_a  = & \frac{1}{2} \times a \times {t_a}^2 \\
    h_v  = & \SI{120}{\metre\per\second\squared}\\
    \end{aligned}
    \end{equation}  
    Equation 1.2 does not look right, because of SI.

    \begin{align*}
    t_a &= \frac{\SI{6}{\metre\per\second}}{\SI{0,6}{\metre\per\second\squared}} \\
    &= \SI{10}{\second}
    \\
    h_a &= \frac{1}{2} \times \SI{6}{\metre\per\second\squared} \times {\SI{10}{\second}}^2 \\
    &= \SI{30}{\metre}
    \\
    h_v  &=  \SI{300}{\metre} - \SI{30}{\metre} - \SI{30}{\metre} \\
    &= \SI{240}{\metre}          
    \\          
    t_v  &=  \frac{\SI{240}{\metre}}{\SI{6}{\metre\per\second}} \\
    &= \SI{40}{\second}          
    \\          
    t_t  &= 2 \times (\SI{10}{\second} + \SI{40}{\second} + \SI{8}{\second}  + \SI{120}{\second}) \\
    &= \SI{356}{\second}                  
    \end{align*}
    Not working at all....

    \begin{table}[h!]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{r l r l}
            $t_a $:&Beschleunigungsdauer  &$v$:&Geschwindigkeit [\SI{}{\metre\per\second}] \\
    \end{tabular}\nonumber
    \end{table}
    This is fine.
    \end{document}
```

Comment: As you might have noticed I am using `detect-all` but it does not seem to work. Am I using it wrong?

Comment: You need to set `\sisetup{math-rm=\mathrm}` back again after `\begin{document}`. 
 See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66743/117534. As for the table headings, if it is not frequent, you can just pass `detect-all` as an option to `\si` to get it back to sans serif.

Comment: As an aside (off-topic), the alignment tabs for align should be placed *before* the `=` sign for proper spacing.

Comment: @Skillmon You are wrong. `\familydefault` is long by default: `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\show\familydefault
\end{document}` gives `> \familydefault=\long macro:
->\rmdefault .`

Comment: @Schweinebacke interesting, I wonder why it is long though...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that siunitx detects the font family by comparing the current family with the `\sffamily` -- and if both are equal as in your case it assumes that you want `math-sf/\mathsf`.

One can demonstrate the effect by using a slightly different sans font. I also use the `[no-math]` option for fontspec to avoid that it changes the mathrm and mathsf fonts:

```
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}    
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\setsansfont{Arial}%[Scale=1.01] %activate to see the difference.
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[]{siunitx}
\sisetup{load-configurations = abbreviations}
\sisetup{locale = DE,group-separator={.}}
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}
\sisetup{detect-all}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Heading}

Test  

\SI{10}{\meter} $\SI{10}{\meter}$  

$\mathrm{mathrm} \mathsf{mathsf}$

\end{document}
```

### without the Scale option mathsf is used in math:

[image]

### with the Scale option mathrm is used in math:

[image]

Imho it is better to keep the three standard families (rm, sf and tt) distinct. If you want your main font to be Arial, set it with `\setmainfont`. And if you want your headings to use the main font too, use the option that does it:

```
\documentclass[egregdoesnotlikesansseriftitles]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,amsmath}

\usepackage[]{siunitx}
\sisetup{load-configurations = abbreviations}
\sisetup{locale = DE,group-separator={.}}
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}
\sisetup{detect-all}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Heading}

Test  

\SI{10}{\meter} $\SI{10}{\meter}$  

$\mathrm{mathrm} \mathsf{mathsf}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the input. Maybe I have to clarify: In your example you now have 3 types of math font: mathrm, mathsf and if if typeset something like $ 10 $ or $ h_a$ the regular timesnewroman math/italic font. Is there a way to have the mathsf for those non, siunitx type of situations? Or is this not even the best practice and would I want to have other font for units?

Comment: A lot is possible but what font to choose for mathrm and mathsf or  as standard math font is a new question. Your current math font is not times, it is computer modern.

Comment: Ah, I just grasped the concept of it. I could make the changes I wanted and I works fine, thanks!

Comment: I get `! Undefined control sequence. <argument> \c_sys_engine_xetex_bool`...

Comment: @Arzigoglu See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/382940/siunitx-and-fontspec-unicode-math

Comment: @Arzigoglu: I just saw that the update is already available (in texlive).