# siunitx and fontspec/unicode-math

Tags: fontspec, siunitx, unicode-math

I found an issue with fontspec and siunitx. There is following error message:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \c_sys_engine_xetex_bool
```

It only happens if fontspec and siunitx are booth loaded, otherwise it does not. It seems like siunitx tests something and `\c_sys_engine_xetex_bool` is not defined.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}    
\usepackage{siunitx}    
\usepackage{fontspec}    
\begin{document}        
    Some Text       
\end{document}
```

I found the corresponding code in siunitx:

```
\AtBeginDocument
  {
    \@ifpackageloaded { fontspec }
      {
        \int_const:Nn \c__siunitx_degree_int    { 176 }
        \@ifpackageloaded { unicode-math }
          { \int_const:Nn \c__siunitx_micro_int { "003BC } }
          { \int_const:Nn \c__siunitx_micro_int { "000B5 } }
        \int_const:Nn \c__siunitx_angstrom_int  { "0212B }
        \int_const:Nn \c__siunitx_ohm_int       { "003A9 }
        \bool_if:NT \c_sys_engine_xetex_bool
          {
```

The rest is too long to present here.

I use up-to-date texlive 2017.

Comment: Fixed by https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/issues/311, sent to CTAN today and thus in TL probably tomorrow

Comment: As a work around you can add **temporarly** `\ExplSyntaxOn
\bool_new:N\c_sys_engine_xetex_bool
\ExplSyntaxOff`.  It won't always do the right thing but avoids the error.

Comment: Thanks for this comment. As I don´t even use xetex, it won´t change anything to me right?

Comment: @JosephWright I noticed that this error is still present on CTAN (in fact, the last update for `siunitx` was a year ago).

Comment: @JP-Ellis The most recent update to CTAN was in August, precisely to fix this issue

Comment: @JosephWright Oh sorry, I was looking at the announcements and the timeline.  Weird that it is still doing that for me then despite having updated TeXLive.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved with an CTAN update.