# Problem with \thesistitle in Masters/Doctoral Thesis template

Tags: templates

I have downloaded the fantastic template for doctoral thesis available in
https://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis.

I have used it before I had already adapted the contents for my thesis. However, when I tried to compile it with MiKTeX after the last update I got this problem:

```
("C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\atbegshi.sty"))
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
               -
l.81 ...end of thesis title}
                                               % Your thesis title, this...

?
```

The problem seems to be within the `\thesistitle` command. However I have checked the .cls file and I can't see any problem with it. I downloaded the original from LaTeXtemplates and got the same results:

```
("C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\csquotes\csquotes.cfg"))
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
               -
l.70 \thesistitle{Thesis Title}
                            % Your thesis title, this is used in the tit...

?
```

This is a minimal working example that gives the same error. I couldn't get rid of the class dependency though:

```
\documentclass[11pt, english, singlespacing, headsepline]{MastersDoctoralThesis}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters

\thesistitle{Resilience of wastewater resource recovery to multiple stress conditions} 

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}

\HRule \\[0.4cm] % Horizontal line
{\huge \bfseries \ttitle\par}\vspace{0.4cm} % Thesis title
\HRule \\[1.5cm] % Horizontal line

\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

Crosspost on LaTeX.org

UPDATE: The provisional solution would be to replace the `\thetitle` command part in the .tex file, with:

```
\newcommand{\ttitle}{Thesis title}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@title}{Thesis title}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Welcome, unfortunately the template is buggy. Are you able to provide a minimal working example that reproduces the given error message? Ideally, it would nit rely on the class itself but using book only. The *buggy* part needs to be copied from the cls to the main file.

Comment: Please add \listfiles to the very begining of the main file and add the file list from the log.

Comment: Hi @Johanes_B, I added `\listfiles` but didn't see any difference in the TeXworks output. Should it produce a .log file? I only see the ones that came with the example.

Comment: The log file is the file that includes the errors.

Comment: By the way: https://github.com/johannesbottcher/MDT-Quick-Manual/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Is it possible that it is not automatically created? I have no new files after trying to compile and getting the error.

Comment: It is created, you stated yourself you get an error. The file will be called main.log but maybe your OS is hiding the file ending.

Comment: Turns out there is a --clean option that needs to be deactivated in preferences, typesetting. Otherwise the .log does not get created. I found it in this entry: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/327666/texworks-not-writing-log-or-aux-files. The file is 1600 lines long, any idea where the file list is produced?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The class abuses `\DeclareDocumentCommand` for defining variables. Anyway, the obvious error is in the second line of

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\thesistitle} { o m }{
        \IfBooleanTF{#1} {\DeclareDocumentCommand{\shorttitle}{ }{#1}
        {\DeclareDocumentCommand{\shorttitle}{}{#2}}}
        \DeclareDocumentCommand{\@title}{ }{#2}
        \DeclareDocumentCommand{\ttitle}{ }{#2}
}
```

where `\IfBooleanTF` makes no sense and should be `\IfValueTF`.

The code should be

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\thesistitle} { o m }{%
   \IfValueTF{#1}{\def\shorttitle{#1}}{\def\shorttitle{#2}}%
   \def\@title{#2}%
   \def\ttitle{#2}%
}
```

or, in a slicker way,

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\thesistitle} { O{#2} m }{%
   \def\shorttitle{#1}%
   \def\@title{#2}%
   \def\ttitle{#2}%
}
```

You can avoid modifying the class by using in the preamble

```
\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand{\thesistitle} { O{#2} m }{%
   \def\shorttitle{#1}%
   \def\@title{#2}%
   \def\ttitle{#2}%
}
\makeatother
```

My preference would go to `\def` instead of `\DeclareDocumentCommand`. However, fixing the class would need weeks of work (for example, `\null\vfill` has no place and the number of unprotected end-of-lines is ***huge***), so I let it go.

Answer (score 6):

The code for the definition of `\thesistitle` is wrong. It uses `\IfBooleanTF` to test for the existence of the optional argument. The correct command is `\IfValueTF`. One can reproduce the error with this document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\begin{document}

%Faulty definition:
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\thesistitle} { o m }{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1} %replace by \IfValueTF
    {\DeclareDocumentCommand{\shorttitle}{ }{#1}
    {\DeclareDocumentCommand{\shorttitle}{}{#2}}}
}

\thesistitle{some text some text}

\end{document}
```

This faulty command gives now an error as due to a change in expl3 you no longer can use undefined booleans. The recent error with siunitx ([siunitx and fontspec/unicode-math](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/382940/siunitx-and-fontspec-unicode-math)) and mhchem (see egreg explanation at the end of this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/383077/2388).

Answer (score 3):

As the code of this template is not really appealing here just a workaround:

```
\documentclass[11pt, english, singlespacing, headsepline]{MastersDoctoralThesis}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters

%\thesistitle{Resilience of wastewater resource recovery to multiple stress conditions} 

\newcommand{\ttitle}{Resilience of wastewater resource recovery to multiple stress conditions}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}

\HRule \\[0.4cm] % Horizontal line
{\huge \bfseries \ttitle\par}\vspace{0.4cm} % Thesis title
\HRule \\[1.5cm] % Horizontal line

\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The same L3/xparse stuff as a few months ago?

Comment: @Johannes_B More recent stuff, with texlive updated \approx one week ago, it worked, with the newest update it does not.

Comment: Thanks @samcarter and @Johannes_B for your help, it worked. But apart from creating the command `\ttitle`, I also had to create the command `\@title` necessary for the abstract section. Only this command couldn't be created as such (TeX said it was illegal), so I used `\atitle` instead, and replaced it in the .cls file.

Comment: @Pau please do not change the cls file, support for further problems will be much harder.

Answer (score 3):

Why the error occurs is explained in other answers. But the simplest solution to the problem seems to be to not even use `\thesistitle`. It doesn't do anything really useful.

```
\documentclass[11pt, english, singlespacing, headsepline]{MastersDoctoralThesis}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters


\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}

{\centering\huge\bfseries \parbox{.7\textwidth}{\centering Resilience of wastewater resource recovery to multiple stress conditions}\par}\vspace{0.4cm} % Thesis title

\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

---

The template was updated to work with recent versions of `xparse` as well as with older ones. Overleaf still runs TeX Live 2016.