# How to change bibliography style for all authors?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I am using the [mastersdoctoral](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis) thesis template from http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com. The bibliography appears with Author et al., both in text and in bibliography section for more than 4 authors, while for 3 or fewer authors all names are written out. I want to have Author et al. for more than 3 in the text and whole author list in the bibliography section. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

My preamble (not much modified from original template):

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Masters/Doctoral Thesis 
% LaTeX Template
% Version 2.5 (27/8/17)
%
% This template was downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Version 2.x major modifications by:
% Vel (vel@latextemplates.com)
%
% This template is based on a template by:
% Steve Gunn (http://users.ecs.soton.ac.uk/srg/softwaretools/document/templates/)
% Sunil Patel (http://www.sunilpatel.co.uk/thesis-template/)
%
% Template license:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[
11pt, % The default document font size, options: 10pt, 11pt, 12pt
%oneside, % Two side (alternating margins) for binding by default, uncomment to switch to one side
english, % ngerman for German
onehalfspacing, % Single line spacing, alternatives: onehalfspacing or doublespacing
%draft, % Uncomment to enable draft mode (no pictures, no links, overfull hboxes indicated)
%nolistspacing, % If the document is onehalfspacing or doublespacing, uncomment this to set spacing in lists to single
liststotoc, % Uncomment to add the list of figures/tables/etc to the table of contents
%toctotoc, % Uncomment to add the main table of contents to the table of contents
%parskip, % Uncomment to add space between paragraphs
%nohyperref, % Uncomment to not load the hyperref package
headsepline, % Uncomment to get a line under the header
%chapterinoneline, % Uncomment to place the chapter title next to the number on one line
%consistentlayout, % Uncomment to change the layout of the declaration, abstract and acknowledgements pages to match the default layout
]{MastersDoctoralThesis} % The class file specifying the document structure
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters

\usepackage{mathpazo} % Use the Palatino font by default
%\usepackage[]{natbib}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex8,style=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex} % Use the bibtex backend with the authoryear citation style (which resembles APA)

\addbibresource{thesis.bib} % The filename of the bibliography

\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes} % Required to generate language-dependent quotes in the bibliography
\usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{morefloats}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\raggedbottom        
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[demo]{rotating}

\usepackage{titlesec} 
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{\large}{\thesubsection.}{1em}{}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{bm}      
%math equations
\let\proof\relax
\let\endproof\relax
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{inputenc}
%\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{citecolor=blue,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black}


%%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MARGIN SETTINGS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\geometry{
    paper=a4paper, % Change to letterpaper for US letter
    inner=3.2cm, % Inner margin
    outer=2.6cm, % Outer margin
    bindingoffset=.5cm, % Binding offset
    top=1.5cm, % Top margin
    bottom=1.5cm, % Bottom margin
    %showframe, % Uncomment to show how the type block is set on the page
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   THESIS INFORMATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\thesistitle{Bn } % Your thesis title, this is used in the title and abstract, print it elsewhere with \ttitle
\supervisor{Prof. Dr. N  \textsc{Top}} % Your supervisor's name, this is used in the title page, print it elsewhere with \supname
\examiner{} % Your examiner's name, this is not currently used anywhere in the template, print it elsewhere with \examname
\degree{Doctor of Philosophy} % Your degree name, this is used in the title page and abstract, print it elsewhere with \degreename
\author{Neon \textsc{Light}} % Your name, this is used in the title  page and abstract, print it elsewhere with \authorname
\addresses{} % Your address, this is not currently used anywhere in the template, print it elsewhere with \addressname

\subject{Immunology} % Your subject area, this is not currently used anywhere in the template, print it elsewhere with \subjectname
\keywords{} % Keywords for your thesis, this is not currently used anywhere in the template, print it elsewhere with \keywordnames
\university{\href{http://www.google.com}{B B}} % Your university's name and URL, this is used in the title page and abstract, print it elsewhere with \univname
\department{\href{http://www.google.com}{Department of Sciences}} % Your department's name and URL, this is used in the title page and abstract, print it elsewhere with \deptname
\group{\href{http://www.google.com}{N N }} % Your research group's name and URL, this is used in the title page, print it elsewhere with \groupname
\faculty{\href{http://www.google.com}{Faculty of Sci}} % Your faculty's name and URL, this is used in the title page and abstract, print it elsewhere with \facname

\AtBeginDocument{
    \hypersetup{pdftitle=\ttitle} % Set the PDF's title to your title
    \hypersetup{pdfauthor=\authorname} % Set the PDF's author to your name
    \hypersetup{pdfkeywords=\keywordnames} % Set the PDF's keywords to your keywords
}

\begin{document} 

    \frontmatter % Use roman page numbering style (i, ii, iii, iv...) for the pre-content pages

    \pagestyle{plain} % Default to the plain heading style until the thesis style is called for the body content

    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %   TITLE PAGE
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    \begin{titlepage}
        \begin{center}

            \vspace*{.06\textheight}
            {\scshape\LARGE \univname\par}\vspace{1.5cm} % Universiteit Utrecht
            \textsc{\Large Doctoral Thesis}\\[0.5cm] % Thesis type

            \HRule \\[0.4cm] % Horizontal line
            {\huge \bfseries \ttitle\par}\vspace{0.4cm} % Thesis title
            \HRule \\[1.5cm] % Horizontal line

            \begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
                \begin{flushleft} \large
                    \emph{Author:}\\
                    {\authorname} % Author name - remove the \href bracket to remove the link
                \end{flushleft}
            \end{minipage}
            \begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
                \begin{flushright} \large
                    \emph{Supervisor:} \\
                    {\supname} % Supervisor name - remove the \href bracket to remove the link  
                \end{flushright}
            \end{minipage}\\[3cm]

            \vfill
            %\centering
            %\includegraphics{logo}
            \large \textit{A thesis submitted in fulfilment of the requirements\\ for the degree of \degreename}\\[0.3cm] % University requirement text
            \textit{in the}\\[0.4cm]
            \groupname\\\deptname\\[2cm] % Research group name and department name

            \vfill

            {\large \today}\\[4cm] % Date
            %\includegraphics{Logo} % University/department logo - uncomment to place it

            \vfill
        \end{center}
    \end{titlepage}

    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %   DECLARATION PAGE
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    \begin{declaration}
        \addchaptertocentry{\authorshipname} % Add the declaration to the table of contents
        \noindent I, \authorname, declare that this thesis titled, \enquote{\ttitle} and the work presented in it are my own. I confirm that:

        \begin{itemize} 
            \item This work was done wholly or mainly while in candidature for a research degree at this University.
            \item Where any part of this thesis has previously been submitted for a degree or any other qualification at this University or any other institution, this has been clearly stated.
            \item Where I have consulted the published work of others, this is always clearly attributed.
            \item Where I have quoted from the work of others, the source is always given. With the exception of such quotations, this thesis is entirely my own work.
            \item I have acknowledged all main sources of help.
            \item Where the thesis is based on work done by myself jointly with others, I have made clear exactly what was done by others and what I have contributed myself.\\
        \end{itemize}

        \noindent Signed:\\
        \rule[0.5em]{25em}{0.5pt} % This prints a line for the signature

        \noindent Date:\\
        \rule[0.5em]{25em}{0.5pt} % This prints a line to write the date
    \end{declaration}

    \cleardoublepage

    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %   QUOTATION PAGE
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    \vspace*{0.2\textheight}

    \noindent\enquote{\itshape }\bigbreak

    \hfill 

    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %   ABSTRACT PAGE
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{abstract}
\addchaptertocentry{\abstractname} % Add the abstract to the table of contents

 The problem can be seen when using this citation: \citep{FiPrWuCa89}, it will appear as 
 Fink et al. 1989 in the text as well as in the bibliography. 
 While this one: \citep{GaMaNaHelene} will appear as a list of all names in both places.



\end{abstract}
\clearpage

\addchaptertocentry{\abstractname} % Add the abstract to the table of contents




    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %   ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    \begin{acknowledgements}
        \addchaptertocentry{\acknowledgementname} % Add the acknowledgements to the table of contents
        The acknowledgements and the people to thank go here, don't forget to include your project advisor\ldots
    \end{acknowledgements}

    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %   LIST OF CONTENTS/FIGURES/TABLES PAGES
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    \tableofcontents % Prints the main table of contents

    \listoffigures % Prints the list of figures

    \listoftables % Prints the list of tables

    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %   ABBREVIATIONS
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    \begin{abbreviations}{ll} % Include a list of abbreviations (a table of two columns)



    \end{abbreviations}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SYMBOLS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        \begin{symbols}{lll} % Include a list of Symbols (a three column table)



%       \addlinespace % Gap to separate the Roman symbols from the Greek
% 
%         $\omega$ & angular frequency & \si{\radian} \\

        \end{symbols}

    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %%  DEDICATION
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    %\dedicatory{For/Dedicated to/To my\ldots} 

    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %   THESIS CONTENT - CHAPTERS
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    \mainmatter % Begin numeric (1,2,3...) page numbering
    \ohead*{}
    \ofoot*{\pagemark}
    \pagestyle{thesis} % Return the page headers back to the "thesis" style

    % Include the chapters of the thesis as separate files from the Chapters folder
    % Uncomment the lines as you write the chapters

    %\include{Chapters/Chapter1}
    %\include{Chapters/Chapter2} 
    %\include{Chapters/Chapter3}
    %\include{Chapters/Chapter4} 
    %\include{Chapters/Chapter5} 
    %\include{Chapters/Chapter6} 
    %\include{Chapters/Chapter7} 


    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %   THESIS CONTENT - APPENDICES
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    %\appendix % Cue to tell LaTeX that the following "chapters" are Appendices

    % Include the appendices of the thesis as separate files from the Appendices folder
    % Uncomment the lines as you write the Appendices  

    %\include{Appendices/AppendixA}
    %\include{Appendices/AppendixB}
    %\include{Appendices/AppendixC}




    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %   BIBLIOGRAPHY
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    \printbibliography 

    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please provide a [compilable document](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), not just a fragment.

Comment: Hello @Bobyandbob I edited my question, hope it explainsthe problem a bit more .

Comment: That template is an abomination (https://github.com/johannesbottcher/templateConfusion, https://github.com/johannesbottcher/templateConfusion/blob/master/ourFamousThesisTemplate.md, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/383150/35864). Try to pass the option `maxbibnames=999` to `biblatex`: `\usepackage[backend=bibtex8,style=authoryear,natbib=true,maxbibnames=999]{biblatex}`

Comment: @moewe: That's really abominable ;-)

Comment: Subfigure is obsolete for many years. You should read an up to date introduction. That way you wouldn't need templates at all.

Comment: @moewe Thanks, it works..It now writes all author names in the bibliography section.  I'd have to agree with you about the template

Comment: @Johannes_B how is this relevant?

Comment: @Trinity: Using outdated templates and packages etc. could cause problems as those packages etc. aren't maintained and do not incorporate changes  in the LaTeX core and other packages on which they might rely.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer this is good advice, I do not use subfigures anyway, just never bothered to delete the option from the preamble. Cheers!

Comment: Would you say this is a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1554/35864

Comment: @moewe suggestions for improvements welcome.

Comment: You should definitely make a concerted effort to remove the cruft and deadwood from the document's preamble. The preamble you posted very much conveys a [Cargo Cult feel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming), characterized chiefly by a "ritual inclusion of code or program structures that serve no real purpose". Do figure out what you really need, and then remove all directives that serve no purpose and/or are actually detrimental.