# Use specific literature citation style

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing

I've been searching for this topic quite a while in the internet (including here) but could not find a solution to my specific problem.

Nevertheless, this is my problem: 
I am currently writing my thesis and need to have a specific literature citation style in my bibliography at the end, which has to look like this:

> Tsikalas, F., Faleide, J.I., Eldholm, O., Wilson, J., 2005. Late Mesozoic–Cenozoic structural and stratigraphic correlations between the conjugate mid-Norway and NE Greenland continental margins, geological development of the northeast Greenland shelf. In: Dore, A.G., Vining, B.A. (Eds.), Petroleum Geology: North-West Europe and Global Perspectives –– Proceedings of the 6th Petroleum Geology Conference, vol. 2. Geological Society, London, pp. 785-801.

Meaning:

Last Name, First Name, year, title, journal with volume (no comma in between!), pages

I am especially having problems telling LaTeX to implement book chapters as seen in the last example with "In: Dore, A.G., Vining, B.A. etc.". I am using JabRef. Do you have any ideas on that or code examples, so that LaTeX takes the field of JabRef proposed as the @incollection field?

Another problem is that I need to write "LASTNAME et al." in the text as soon as it says three or more authors.

Do you have any ideas?

This is my code so far (neglecting anything else that doesn't take citations into account):

```
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[
12pt, % The default document font size, options: 10pt, 11pt, 12pt
oneside, % Two side (alternating margins) for binding by default, uncomment to switch to one side
english,ngerman % ngerman for German
onehalfspacing, % Single line spacing, alternatives: onehalfspacing or doublespacing
%draft, % Uncomment to enable draft mode (no pictures, no links, overfull hboxes indicated)
nolistspacing, % If the document is onehalfspacing or doublespacing, uncomment this to set spacing in lists to single
liststotoc, % Uncomment to add the list of figures/tables/etc to the table of contents
toctotoc, % Uncomment to add the main table of contents to the table of contents
%parskip, % Uncomment to add space between paragraphs
nohyperref, % Uncomment to not load the hyperref package
headsepline, % Uncomment to get a line under the header
%chapterinoneline, % Uncomment to place the chapter title next to the number on one line
%consistentlayout, % Uncomment to change the layout of the declaration, abstract and acknowledgements pages to match the default layout
]{MastersDoctoralThesis} % The class file specifying the document structure

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{palatino} % Use the Palatino font by default
%\renewcommand*\rmdefault{ppl}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{°}{\degree}
\usepackage{graphicx,wrapfig}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear,firstinits=true, 
doi=false,isbn=false,url=false,maxbibnames=3,natbib=true]%
{biblatex} % Use the bibtex backend with the authoryear citation style (which resembles APA)

\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}

\newrobustcmd*{\parentexttrack}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \blx@blxinit
  \blx@setsfcodes
  \blx@bibopenparen#1\blx@bibcloseparen
  \endgroup}

\AtEveryCite{%
  \let\parentext=\parentexttrack%
  \let\bibopenparen=\bibopenbracket%
  \let\bibcloseparen=\bibclosebracket}

\newdateformat{monthyeardate}{\monthname[\THEMONTH], \THEYEAR}

\addbibresource{jabref.bib} % The filename of the bibliography

\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes} % Required to generate language-dependent quotes in the bibliography

\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook,inproceedings,article,misc]{citetitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook,inproceedings,article,misc]{title}{#1}
```

Thank you very much for your help!

All the best,

Max

Comment: Regarding the et al abbreviation for references with three or more authors, you can use `maxbibnames=3`. Additionally, please turen your code fragment into a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/134144).

Comment: Please edit your posting to provide the bib code for the three entries .

Comment: The formatting of the `author` blocks is not uniform across the three examples you provided. In the first, there's space between the first-name initials, and there's an `and` immediately before the name of the final author. In contrast, in examples 2 and 3, there's no space between the initials, and there's no "and" between the penultimate and the final author. Is this difference deliberate?

Comment: While questions like "how can I get this style <example here>" are not unheard of on this site, they don't make for a great Q&A. A good question would revolve around one specific issue, e.g. 'how can I make `biblatex` only show one name and et al. in citations', or 'how can I get the `editor` in `@incollection` before the `booktitle`'. You are essentially asking people to write an entire style for you: People may do this, but don't count on it.

Comment: @Mico actually, is there a guide/tutorial somewhere to learn the inner workings of biblatex or how to write one's own bib style? I mean, not totally from scratch, but based on an existing style, maybe. I could read the entire biblatex documentation, but that's hardly written in a tutorialesque format.

Comment: @Mico First, thank you all for your responses!
In fact, I am looking for a citation style as proposed in the last example with "Tsikalas, F. ..."; I've just edited my post. I've also edited my code so that it outputs "... et al." with more than three authors.

Comment: @MaxPy - Please see the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/427031/5001) I posted a short while ago. It employs BibTeX, the `natbib` citation management and the bibliography style called `elsarticle-harv` (optionally modified).

Comment: You may want to consider that despite the name "`MastersDoctoralThesis`" is not considered the pinnacle of creation when it comes to LaTeX document classes. In fact some people, amongst which I definitely count myself, would advise others not to use this class. For a bit of background read https://github.com/johannesbottcher/templateConfusion and (in German, sorry, maybe you can read German, you load `ngerman` after all) https://komascript.de/latexvorlage. For an example why the class is bad, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/383150/35864 (could be about an older version).

Comment: @moewe any suggestions to make that class better are welcome. That was how I got into this however.

Comment: @Johannes_B There are still a lot of unprotected line ends, the version information in the header and `\ProvidesClass` don't match in the LaTeXtemplates version. Other things are just my personal opinion (does it really need `\graphicspath{{Figures/}{./}}`?) The license of the template and its parts could be stated more clearly: As I see it now the `.cls` is LPPL while the `.tex` is CC, that makes sense, but should made clearer in a README or LICENSE file - and the reasoning could be explained. Normally LPPL license notices look different and list the status (maintained, author-maintained) ...

Comment: ... as well as the maintainer. But I guess that could be inferred from the rest of the header. My other problems with this class/template are just conceptional: It tries to do too many things, but of course it can't do anything. So the average user will end up adding features and packages that are not there, while at the same time using only a fraction of what the class provides. The class also has no official documentation, no changelog and the LaTeXtemplates download page does not even list the version number and date.

Comment: @moewe You seem to be the first one who noticed the version mismatch. Considering the license: At least there is a proper license, there was none before. Line ends, i would correct them, if i knew which ones need to be escaped. To the other stuff, it is a template. That is what templates do. I inherited a bunch of silly stuff and tried to kick out the worst parts. You know i am not a friend of templates myself and i am regretting having touched that thing. You do know the history: https://github.com/johannesbottcher/templateConfusion/blob/master/ourFamousThesisTemplate.md

Comment: Moewe pointed out what is wrong with the class. I cannot recommend to use it. He also gave you alternatives. But reading your comments, you do not know how LaTeX works. I recommend to read an introduction. You do *not* need a template for a thesis. -> https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Scientific_Reports

Answer (score 2):

The standard styles place the `editor` after the `booktitle` in `@incollection`s. You can either use one of the solutions in [Move names of editors followed by (Ed./Eds.) and a comma before title in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/173638/35864) or you can try one of the styles of my [`biblatex-ext`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ext) bundle. `biblatex-ext` has an option `innamebeforetitle` that moves the `editor` name before the `booktitle`. That style also offers a simple interface to remove the parentheses around the year in the bibliography and for square brackets in citations. Have a look at the documentation of [`biblatex-ext`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-ext/biblatex-ext.pdf) for more.

The modifications are straightforward to understand if you search for the modified item in the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) and the [`biblatex-ext` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-ext/biblatex-ext.pdf).

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ext-authoryear,
  giveninits=true, uniquename=init, maxbibnames=999, maxcitenames=3,
  doi=false, isbn=false, url=false,
  innamebeforetitle=true, articlein=false,
  natbib=true,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareOuterCiteDelims{parencite}{\bibopenbracket}{\bibclosebracket}

\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}
\renewrobustcmd*{\bibinitdelim}{}

\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}
\DeclareDelimFormat{translatortypedelim}{\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{translatortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

\DeclareFieldFormat{biblabeldate}{#1}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{citetitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{booktitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{journaltitle}{#1}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{innametitledelim}{\addcomma\space}

\renewbibmacro*{pubinstorg+location+date}[1]{%
  \printlist{#1}%
  \setunit*{\publocdelim}%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\locdatedelim}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{pages}{#1}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{tsikalas,
  author    = {Tsikalas, F. and Faleide, J. I. and Eldholm, O. and Wilson, J.},
  title     = {Late {Mesozoic--Cenozoic} structural and stratigraphic correlations between the conjugate {mid-Norway} and {NE} {Greenland} continental margins},
  editor    = {Doré, A. G. and Vining, B. A.},
  booktitle = {Petroleum Geology: {North-West} {Europe} and Global Perspectives},
  booktitleaddon = {Proceedings of the 6th Petroleum Geology Conference},
  volume    = {2},
  pages     = {785--801},
  year      = {2005},
  doi       = {10.1144/0060785},
  publisher = {Geological Society},
  location  = {London},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\autocite{sigfridsson,westfahl:space,pines,moraux,tsikalas}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

*edit: `biblatex-ext` [v0.4 changes the names of a few macros](https://github.com/moewew/biblatex-ext/blob/7d2e2f1be11f68dcdec62897e1e2afeaa3809e80/CHANGES.md). Use the new names.*

Comment: I suspect the author's formatting requirements include *not* showing the prefix "pp." before the `pages` field in entries of type  `@article`.

Comment: @Mico Possibly, this is changed now, thanks for the heads-up. The question has been edited multiple times though, and as you noted yourself some of the original desiderata were inconsistent. I didn't expect to get everything right at the first pass with that little information to go by.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! This is actually exactly what I am looking for. However, I implemented your code and it is not running. I guess the class MasterDoctoralThesis and "usepackage babel" don't like each other. Furthermore, it does not find the biblatex.sty file. The error messages are actually very long (up to 100).

Comment: @MaxPy I deliberately did not use `MasterDoctoralThesis` in my MWE, because I advise people not to use it. Anyway, `MasterDoctoralThesis` loads `babel` already so you don't need to load `babel` as I do in my MWE. It is also not unlikely that you system may be too old and/or does not have `biblatex-ext` installed. Do you use MikTeX or TeX live? Make an update of your system report back with the first error.

Comment: @moewe Thanks for your quick response! I use Texmaker 4.5 (compiled with Qt 4.7.2 and Poppler 0.22.5) on a Macbook Pro. Initially, I downloaded the MasterDoctoralThesis as a template and adapted it to my needs. However, if I comment the MasterDoctoral command, it - of course - crashes. The errors occur at literally every line when adding the new code lines. It does not recognize the ext-authoryear style nor any other written in that command. Furthermore, the \DeclareDelimFormat commands cannot be read as well. It works if I use my initial \usepackage{backend=bibtex etc. ...} command.

Comment: @MaxPy Texmaker is only your editor, I would need to know the TeX distribution that you installed. Since you have a Macbook I assume it is TeX live/MacTeX. On that system `biblatex-ext` is not available yet. If you have adapted `MasterDoctoralThesis` without renaming the file you may be in breach of the license agreement (IANAL, I assume this is not a problem for personal use). You can't comment out the `MasterDoctoralThesis` line, you need a `\documentclass` after all. If your system is outdated, some of the commands I used will be unknown to your system.

Comment: @moewe So this means that I would have to re-write my code for a class other than MasterDoctoralThesis? ... Yes, it is TeX Live. Are there any other options to implement your code into my system with some minor changes? Thank you for your response in advance!

Comment: @MaxPy I would strongly advise you not to use `MasterDoctoralThesis`, [but rather to start with one of the standard or KOMA classes](https://komascript.de/latexvorlage). Unfortunately the modification needed to implement this without `biblatex-ext` are not going to be minor. I explicitly used that package to allow for a simple solution. It is entirely possible though and I might have a look if I'm bored tomorrow. Since I don't know how outdated your system is, I don't know what commands can be used, so that could be problematic.

Comment: @moewe Instead of the MasterDoctoralThesis class, which class would you recommend for my thesis? Since this was a template, the class was unfortunately the last thing that caught my attention. However, I had some minor problems in the past with this class but could figure it out. Do you have any suggestions on how to re-write it to an appropriate class? Thank you!

Comment: @MaxPy Depends on what you want. I would certainly look at `scrreprt` and `scrbook` (or `report`/`book`): https://komascript.de/latexvorlage

Comment: @moewe Thank you for your advice. However, I do not see myself re-writing the whole Latex code from the MasterDoctoralThesis class to a e.g. scrbook class. Aren't there any possibilities to quickly transform the needed citation style with the MasterDoctoral class? Even if things are worked out anyhow?

Comment: @MaxPy What version of `biblatex` do you use?

Comment: @MaxPy You could try https://gist.github.com/moewew/e34a6c17903ad0f7483b8fcb5872534e. That version works without `biblatex-ext` and tries to be compatible with older `biblatex` versions as well. No guarantee that everything works as expected, though, since I only have `biblatex` 3.11 and did the backwards compatibility based on my recollection of how things used to be.

Comment: @moewe Sorry for the stupid question, but where can I check the biblatex version?

Comment: @MaxPy Run a document with the contest `\listfiles\documentclass{article}\usepackage{biblatex}\begin{document}Hallo\end{document}` and check the reported version at the end of the `.log` file. (EDIT: It's `\listfiles` with an **`s`**, I forgot that initially, sorry)

Comment: @moewe Thank you, I will check that immediately! Meanwhile a totally different question since I am still working on my citation style: If you have a look at:
Blystad, P., H. Brekke, R. Færseth, B. Larsen, J. Skogseid, and B. Tørudbakken (1995). Structural elements of the Norwegian continental shelf Part II: The Norwegian Sea Region. Norwegian Petroleum Directorate Bulletin No. 8. ... my question now is: How do I get rid of 1) the comma before the "and" and 2) exchange the "and" with a "&" not only in the text (I already did that) but also in the reference list?

Comment: @moewe This is what I got when I ran your code line: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2015.7.17)

Comment: @MaxPy I need the `biblatex` version it will be shown towards the end of the `.log` for the example I showed you. But TeX live 2015 is already quite old. Chances are you don't even have version 3.3. The current version is 3.11! Any chances for an update? (Remember: updates are always risky, especially if you are half-way into an important document and the deadline is near)

Comment: @moewe You are absolutely right with your last sentence. Therefore, I would rather not risk it. However, I have adapted my document so far, but there are still some questions left. Maybe, we could go through them instead quickly? ... Basically, this is what I have so far: Cloetingh, S. and H. Kooi (1992). Intraplate stresses and dynamical aspects of rifted basins. In: Tectonophysics 215.1-2, 167–185. ... BUT, I want it like this: Cloetingh, S. & H. Kooi (1992): Intraplate stresses and dynamical aspects of rifted basins, Tectonophysics 215, 1-2, 167–185. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @MaxPy Please consider asking a new question with a proper [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) (compare the code in your question to the code in Mico's or my answer) for that. This has become quite long already and I would really need to so what you have so far and what you are trying.

Comment: @MaxPy FWIW https://gist.github.com/moewew/e34a6c17903ad0f7483b8fcb5872534e is a version of my answer above that should work with your ancient version of `biblatex`. Of course I can't test so I had to rely on guessing. Not everything will work.

Answer (score 1):

If you can make do with a BibTeX/`natbib`-based solution, the `elsarticle-harv` bibliography style comes extremely close to your formatting requirements.

---

The only salient difference I can readily detect between your stated formatting requirements and what's produced by the `elsarticle-harv` is that `elsarticle-harv` inserts spaces between adjacent given-name initials. If you wanted to "fix" this minor discrepancy, I suggest you proceed as follows:

- Find the file `elsarticle-harv.bst` in your TeX distribution. Make a copy of this file and call the copy, say, `elsarticle-harv-mod.bst`. (Feel free to pick a snazzier name...) Don't edit an original file of the TeX distribution directly.
- Open the file `elsarticle-harv-mod.bst` in a text editor -- the editor you use to edit your tex files will do fine -- and locate the function `format.names`. (In my copy of the file, this function starts on line 377.)
- In this function, locate the following line:

  ```
        "{vv~}{ll}{, jj}{, f.}" format.name$
  ```

  Change it to

  ```
        "{vv~}{ll}{, jj}{, f{.}.}" format.name$
  ```

  Note the extra `{.}` particle.
- *Optional*: If you wish to suppress the issue number in entries of type `@article`, you should locate the function `format.vol.num.pages` (it starts on line 799 in my copy of the bst file) and comment out (or just delete...) the following 10 lines of code (lines 809 to 818 in the file):

  ```
    number empty$
      'skip$
      {
        "~(" number * ")" * *
        volume empty$
          { "there's a number but no volume in " cite$ * warning$ }
          'skip$
        if$
      }
    if$
  ```
- Save the file `elsarticle-harv-mod.bst` either in the directory where your main tex file is located or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the latter method, be sure to update the filename database of your TeX distribution suitably.
- In your main tex file, load the `natbib` package with the option `authoryear`. Doing so ensures that the citation call-outs will be formatted as "FirstAuthor et al" whenever an entry has three or more authors (or editors).

---

Here's how entries of type `@article` and `@incollection` would look like:

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@incollection{uuu,
  author       = "Tsikalas, Filippos and Faleide, Jan Inge
                  and Eldholm, Olav and Wilson, Jonas",
  editor       = "Anthony G. Dor{\'e} and Bernie A. Vining",
  title        = "Late {Mesozoic--Cenozoic} structural and
                  stratigraphic correlations between the
                  conjugate mid-{Norway} and {NE
                  Greenland} continental margins,
                  geological development of the northeast
                  {Greenland} shelf",
  booktitle    = "Petroleum Geology: North-West Europe and
                  Global Perspectives---Proceedings of
                  the 6th Petroleum Geology Conference",
  year         = 2005,
  publisher    = "Geological Society",
  address      = "London",
  volume       = 2,
  pages        = "785--801",
}
@article{vvv,
  author       = "Anna Maria Author and Brenda Michelle
                  Buthor and Carla Miranda Cuthor",
  title        = "Thoughts",
  year         = 3001,
  journal      = "Circularity Today",
  volume       = 1,
  number       = 2,
  pages        = "3--4",
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath} % Palatino text and math font
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\setlength{\bibhang}{0pt}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv-mod}

\begin{document}
\citep{uuu}, \citet{vvv}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```