# How to use only serif fonts in whole document?

Tags: fonts, koma-script

I'm wondering how to use only serif fonts in whole document. Remark: I use one of the KOMA Script document classes, which employ sans-serif fonts for chapter and sectioning headers.

I've managed to change the table of contents with KOMA, but e.g. setkoma commands won't work for all the headings.

This is my main document:

```
\input{chapter/header}
\setlength{\unitlength}{1mm}
\makeindex
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}%

\begin{spacing}{1}%Normal Spacing
\renewcommand*{\theHchapter}{0.\arabic{chapter}} %so that no double Chapter I (prob with hyperref)
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1} %No number in front of Chapter
\maketitle 

\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\hfill
\clearpage

\input{chapter/Declaration}

\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\hfill
\clearpage

\input{chapter/Abstract}

\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\hfill
\clearpage

\renewcommand*{\theHchapter}{\arabic{chapter}} %so that no double Chapter I (prob with hyperref)
    %TOC etc.
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4} %Numbers in front of Chapter etc
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4} 
\pagenumbering{Roman}
```

This is my header.tex:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,%
                            english,%
                            numbers=noenddot,%not 1.1. but 1.1 (früher: pointlessnumbers)
                            oneside,%
                            bibliography=totoc,%früher: bibtotoc
                            listof=totoc,%früher: liststotoc
                            %draft
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\pdfoutput=1
\pdfcompresslevel=9
%\DeclareGraphicsRule{.tif}{bmp}{}{}            %see epslatex.ps
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg,.mps} %see epslatex.ps
\graphicspath{{bilder/}}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}%zuständig für umlaute und scharfes s (ß)
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: `\renewcommand\sfdefault{\rmdefault}` ?

Comment: Are you looking for the document class option `egregdoesnotlikesansseriftitles`?

Comment: I can't compile your mwe.

Comment: Please don't remove your code. You might consider editing it to make it more minimal, but deleting it now you've got an answer is just destructive.

Comment: Possible duplicat of [Headers and font in KOMA-script](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/313149/43317)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To make all the headings "no sans serif" - or for short "serif" -
there is a special documentclass option:

```
\documentclass[egregdoesnotlikesansseriftitles]{scrbook}

\begin{document}
\chapter{test}
test
\end{document}
```

#### Update for koma v3.39 or newer

The option now has the boring name `sfdefaults=false`:

```
\documentclass[sfdefaults=false]{scrbook}

\begin{document}
\chapter{test}
test
\end{document}
```

Comment: You've got to be kidding me!

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes no :) easy to remember name, don't you think?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes you have  to be _really annoying_ to make a package author add such an option:-)

Comment: Immortalized!!!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle "The only thing worse than being talked about...is not being talked about." -O. Wilde

Comment: You have to buy me a new keyboard: I spit almost all my coffee onto it. Oh, and you'll get my doctor's invoice too: I think I ripped my diaphragm laughing...

Comment: @campa please direct your complains at egreg :)

Comment: It worked! Tried to do it beforehand, but it completly changed the documents format ... . Thank you so much! Wasted hours on this

Comment: I suspect that the option "egregdoesnotlikesansseriftitles" was, until now, the most obscure and/or least-documented of all options of the koma-script document classes. No more! :-)

Comment: Why did they choose this name? Quite hard to remember imho ...

Comment: Everybody should know `egreg`. The rest is intuition.

Comment: @mldmnn I guess the name was chosen because of this comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/289853/why-does-koma-script-mix-serifs-and-sans-serifs#comment701328_289853

Comment: @Mico There are already a few answers about it, e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/382974/36296

Comment: @mldmnn, if you were serious in your question, just go to https://tex.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all and notice who is the #1 all-time user here.  `egreg` is at the pinnacle of the TeX food chain.

Comment: @mldmnn Another way to picture it is this, your profile, https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/156599/mldmnn, shows your presence on this site has reached a total of 28 people, at this moment.  Compare it to https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg, which shows that, at the moment, egreg has reached a total of 33.7 million people by his presence here.  One may not always agree with egreg's preferences, but one should never foolishly ignore his advice.  Gravitas!!!

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes - If egreg is the equivalent of an Orca on TeX.SE, what are we? Dolphins? Sea lions? Baby seals?!

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes The food chain theory makes total sense! It also explains why David Carlisle has the second most rep, because `egregdoesnotlikepinapplepizza`, thus he is safe from the food chain

Comment: Unlike the rest of us cud-chewing ruminators on the TeX prairie.  Mere sport for the apex predators.

Comment: Best option name ever!

Comment: I must be at the bottom of the chain since I'm vegan.

Comment: That's what I'd call an "egregious" option! :)