# Change Font for part, section, subsection, ... KOMA scrartcl-class

Tags: sectioning, formatting, koma-script

I am using the `KOMA scrartcl-class`

```
\documentclass[listof=totoc,toc=sectionentrywithdots,DIV=14]{scrartcl}
```

Is there a way to change the font-style of the `part`, `section`, `subsection` and `subsubsection` globally?

Comment: That would probably be `\setkomafont{disposition}{......}`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25845/105447.

Comment: You can also use `\addtokomafont` or `\setkomafont` to change the global settings for a each section level individually: `\addtkomafont{part}{\Large}` etc.

Comment: I agree this is a duplicate, but (for consideration in future cases), isn't this a little too fast?...

Comment: In which way do you want to change the font. In case you want it to be serif, have a loot at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/418912/36296

Comment: @samcarter, I'd forgotten about this one! (Not sure how!)

Comment: Font-style can also be the size or the shape?